# Scala Array map function documentation (PSSQ #1)

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit-conversion, api-doc

*PSSQ stand for Possibly Stupid Scala Question* :)

Getting to know Scala a little bit, and in the obligatory Hello World example (code below) the arguments to the main function is an array of strings.

```
object HelloWorld
{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
    {
        args.map((arg:String) => arg.toUpperCase());
        printf("%s %s!", "Hello", "World");
    }
}
```

In the example, I'm using the `map()` function on the array. However, when I check the Scala API documentation, `map()` isn't listed as one of the functions available for `Array`. Is there some kind of magic going on, or am I missing something obvious in the API documentation?

Comment: Don't use that style of identation for `{`. Put it on the same line of declaration, whatever else you may do. You may dislike how it looks, but it will save you trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of one key feature of Scala called implicit conversions. There is plenty of documents about them on the net, for instance see this one: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6

The upcoming Scala 2.9 REPL can help you find out which might be involved here:

```
scala> :implicits -v
```

... looking for Array we find several ones that go to `mutable.ArrayOps`. The scaladoc for that one: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.html

This means that since the implicit conversion method `refArrayOps` is in scope (in the default `Predef`), whenever you try to call a method on an `Array` that is not defined for `Array` but for `ArrayOps`, scala will insert (implicitly) the conversion, hence you actually have

```
Predef.refArrayOps(args).map(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: `map` is actually a method on the `Traversable` trait, which is included by `Array`.

The hard answer: `Array` doesn't really extend `Traversable` anymore (iirc), but when `Traversable` methods are called on an `Array` instance, there is an implicit conversion that happens in order to allow that to work.